# Subject in "Over there is where I'll be."

Tags: subjects, subject-verb-inversion

Here's a conversation between a receptionist of a hotel and a man wanting to meet a girl living in the hotel:

> **Man:** Is she in?
>
> **Receptionist:** Just missed her, actually, but you're welcome to wait.
>
> **Man:** Okay. Maybe I will. She probably won't be that long, right?
>
> **Receptionist:** Once she went out and didn't come back for six months. But feel free to sit. Over there.
>
> **Man:** *Over there is where I'll be.*

In this context, what is the subject of the last sentence? *Over there* or *where I'll be*?

If it's *Over there*, is this an instance of a prepositional phrase being a subject?

Comment: If you're only looking at the *semantics* of the sentence, it means the same thing as *I will be over there.* In terms of its meaning, the man is the subject.

Comment: @JasonBassford Do you mean "I" is the subject? If so, that's not the answer I'm looking for. I'm looking for a grammatical subject, if you know what I mean.

Comment: The construction of this sentence ascribes a quality to "over there"; it is where I'll be. Does this phrasing help you identify the subject?

Comment: I would not say that the sentence ascribes a quality to *over there*. Instead, it ascribes a location to *where I'll be*. *Red is the colour of the apple.* What's the subject of that sentence? Just because something comes before the word *is*, that doesn't necessarily mean that it's the subject of the sentence.

Comment: @JasonBassford *Subjects* are not about semantics. They're about syntax.

Comment: @JasonBassford You seem to be suggesting that in your example _Red_ is not the subject. I'm curious how you can be so sure. If your example were _Red is the apple_, I'd agree that _Red_ isn't the subject. But in your example, _Red_ can be a noun as well as an adjective, so _Red_ can be the subject.

Comment: @Araucaria Syntax cannot be parsed *without* semantics. Without any understanding of individual words or how they function in relation to each other, the sentence in question would just be seen as *"111 222 333 444 555 666."* Consider the sentence "*they are cooking apples.*" What are the roles of *they* and *cooking*? Does the sentence describe people in the kitchen baking, or is it only describing apples? If semantics truly played no role, the answer would be simple.

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't disagre that we can't establish the syntax without some semantics. However, that does not affect the fact that syntax is not about semantics, and the erm subject is not a semantic term, or one describing semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR The subject of the sentence is indeed the preposition phrase *over there*.

---

We normally expect the subjects of sentences to be noun phrases or sometimes clauses. However, they can occasionally be adjective phrases, preposition phrases or even adverb phrases.

Preposition phrases can be the subjects of clauses using specifying, but not ascriptive *BE*. In the Original Poster's example, *BE* is being used in its specifying and not ascriptive sense and therefore this preposition phrase is contender for subject of the sentence.

Preposition phrases do sometimes appear as complements at the beginning of clauses which display subject complement inversion—where they are not subjects. However, this usually occurs when the locative phrase occurs with the verb *BE* used in its ascriptive sense:

> Over there are some tweezers.

Here the subject of the clause is *some tweezers*, and the preposition phrase *over there* is giving us some information about the location of these tweezers. Notice that the verb *BE* agrees with *tweezers* here, and not the preposition phrase *over there*. However, this is different from the OP's sentence where the verb *BE* has an equative meaning, and the sentence could be modelled as:

> Over there = where I'll be.

Notice that we cannot do this with the other example:

> Over there = some tweezers.

These facts would seem to rule out the Original Poster's example being a case of subject complement inversion. It *is* possible for us to have subject dependent inversion with specifying *BE*, but only in very flowery poetic type environments, very different from the Original Poster's example:

> The king of the meadows am I.

There is no indication that any other phrase has inverted with the phrase *over there* in this sentence therefore.

The phrase *over there*, then, is in the canonical subject position, occurring before the verb, and we have good reason to believe it to be th subject.

We could do the subject auxiliary inversion test to double check if *over there* is the subject. If we turn the sentence into a question, the subject should invert with the auxiliary *BE*:

> Is over there where I'll be?

Here we see the phrase *over there* has inverted with the  verb *is* giving further evidence that it is the subject.

Lastly, outside of imperative constructions, all well-formed English sentences must include a subject and a predicate.  By reducing the sentence using pro-forms to substitute in for these two parts of the clause, we can tell which bit of the original sentence is the subject, by seeing what the subject pronoun is standing in for:

> Over there is where I'll be.
>
> It is.

In the second sentence above the word *it* appears to be standing in for the preposition phrase *over there*. The verb *is* is standing in for *is where I'll be*. Because the subject *it* has replaced the subject of the original clause, we can see that the subject of the original clause is *over there*.

In short, all of the evidence points to the preposition phrase *over there* being the subject of the example sentence.

Comment: Most puzzling why anyone would want to downvote this answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh, didn't you want to download it? ;-) PS Have you finished your PhD?

Comment: \*grumble\* stoopid autocorrect! No, I’d have to start it first in order to finish it. :-p

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh, I was sure you were already torturing yourself with one ... You should definitely try it. I hope your non PhD adventures are going well.

Comment: I did apply, but sadly not one of the five applicants from my programme got a position.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, they're missing out in my humble opinion. Hope things are panning out well and your ample skills are being well-utilised and appreciated.

Comment: Upon reading your answer, I take it that your answer that the subject is _over there_ doesn't change depending on context. Am I right?

Comment: @JK2 Yes, I think that's right. Unless it is a "the manager am I" style sentence, which isn't very likely.

Comment: Wouldn't a purely equative copula simply render subject and complement indistinguishable?  In your last example, I see nothing to tell me whether "it" represents *a place in that direction* or *the location assigned to you*.

Answer (score 2):

The short version: "Over there" is the subject of your sentence.

Why?

A simple rule of thumb is that the subject is what comes before the verb -- this is the case in almost every type of sentence in English, and it's the case here.

But if you want a little deeper understanding, remember that this is a roundabout way of saying

> "I'll be over there"

The man could have said it that way, but he didn't.

Also, consider that the sentence uses a stative verb ("is") with a [predicate complement](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/predicate-complements-2/) ("where I'll be"). The complement essentially gives a new name to the subject. One of the ways to tell if you have a predicate complement is by reversing the sentence -- so

> "Where I'll be is over there"

makes sense, even if it sounds a little awkward.

But you don't simply choose one word order over the other willy-nilly, you do it to fit the sentence into the context ( there's that word again) of the overall conversation/text.

First of all, the previous sentence has the receptionist saying

> But feel free to sit. Over there.

so "over there" has already been introduced into the conversation.  The man could just say "I'll be over there", or "Yes, ma'am" (let's assume "ma'am" for simplicity's sake) 
, or even just "OK", but he's flirting with the receptionist a little, so he decides to reply

> Over there is where I'll be.

So, "over there" is the subject of the sentence because it's become the subject of the conversation.

(I imagine some old WWI veteran sitting in the lobby, overhearing this conversation,  getting annoyed at the man's facetiousness, and breaking out into a loud rendition of "Over There!")

Comment: I also imagine that the man can only be [Archie Goodwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archie_Goodwin_(character)) because that conversation reads like [Rex Stout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rex_Stout) wrote it).

Comment: The dialogue comes from here: https://www.planetclaire.tv/quotes/gossipgirl/season-one/the-wild-brunch/

Comment: @Mari-LouA That whole script reads like something out of a Nero Wolfe novel. All we need is a fat man, a brownstone on West 35th and a murder or two.

Comment: +1 for this: "So 'over there' has already been introduced into the conversation."

Comment: @Araucaria You misread my comment. That was a plus sign, not a minus sign. I *upvoted* your answer because you quite rightly pointed out that the *context* of the sentence had already established "over there" as the subject of conversation. ;)

Comment: @JasonBassford Unfortunately auraucaria muddied the waters by posting a comment under my answer (the one you upvoted) instead of their own (which some unknown person downvoted).

Comment: @Spencer Oh! And I just added to the confusion.

Comment: @JasonBassford So, again: any feedback on the downvote on my post? (Sorry, Spencer. Will delete my comment here upon JB's response)

Comment: Your answer is the same as that of @Araucaria, the difference being that the reason for your answer is based on context as you put it at the end: "So, _over there_ is the subject of the sentence because it's become the subject of the conversation." Does that mean under different context you might not consider _over there_ as the subject? I'm asking this because the other answer will reach the same conclusion regardless of context.

Comment: @JK2 If the context were different enough to matter, the word order would be different, and OP would be asking about a different sentence. "Context" in this case merely gives the reader another tool to figure out what is already written.

Comment: @JK2 [The Wikipedia article on inversion in English](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject–verb_inversion_in_English) and [another Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_copular_constructions) try to argue that the subject can come after "is" in a predicate complement sentence, but it's pretty weak.

Comment: What if the receptionist didn't say _Over there._? Could the man still say _Over there is where I'll be._?

Comment: @JK2 What if the writer hadn't written the receptionist's dialogue with a hostile "Over there"? Is there a ghost of a chance they would have chosen to write the man's reply as "Over there is where I'll be"? Assuming the man isn't doing a Yoda impersonation?

Comment: @JK2 A great point there: "What if the receptionist didn't say *Over there*?" Yes, what if? Could the man still say "Over there is where I'll be?" Yes, for sure. (Do let me know when she eventually turns up, **over there** is where I will be.) -- *Over there* is now the subject because that's what I am talking  about, not myself.